# Rails 3 Streaming Video or Rails HTTP Streaming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, video-streaming, html5-video

I recently implemented JP video player or J Player in my Rails 3 app to stream video tutorials, but issue is video is not streamed in chunks means if size of video is 100MB then after that 100MB gets downloaded on browser then only video will play. To overcome this issue i have implemented http streaming using this rails cast http://railscasts.com/episodes/266-http-streaming
Even then the video is getting fully downloaded. I am not able to understand what wrong i have done.
When i am using curl -i command it shows me Transfer-Encoding: chunked but it is not working as youtube or other video sites work.

Answer (score 0):

The "streaming" you have setted up by following the RailsCast is not the "streaming" you want. You are "streaming" your view (rendered HTML), but you want to stream your media.

jPlayer supports streaming (provided you have encoded your video in a proper container), now you have to add streaming media support to your web server. All popular web servers have modules to do that.